# How to create a date time usage tracker in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, change-tracking

I'm trying to create a usage tracker flagging items that have the same ID within 14 days of the last ID flagged. So if the same ID occurs within 14 days of the first ID no flag, if it occurs outside 14 days of the first flag then it becomes the second flag per ID.

I've tried used `.ffill() .groupby .rolling` These help find duplicates within 14 days but do not help with the rolling flags. I think the solution probably lies in some time of `for` loop with an expanded window?

Starting code

```
df:
date     id
1/1/19      38
1/5/19      16
1/10/19     38 
1/15/19     38
1/21/19     38
1/30/19     16
2/2/19      38
2/2/19      38
2/3/19      38
```

What I need to end up with

```
df2:
date     id       flag    most recent flag
1/1/19      38     True        1/1/19
1/5/19      16     True        1/5/19  
1/10/19     38     False       1/1/19
1/15/19     38     True        1/15/19
1/21/19     38     False       1/15/19
1/30/19     16     True        1/30/19 
2/2/19      38     True        2/2/19   
2/2/19      38     False       2/2/19   
2/3/19      38     False       2/2/19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for keep you waiting

Here is the code for generating df as shown above

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date':['1/1/19','1/5/19','1/10/19','1/15/19','1/21/19','1/30/19','2/2/19','2/2/19','2/3/19'], 
'id':[38,16,38,38,38,16,38,38,38]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

And, these are the other columns I created before calculating your flag

```
df['days_ago'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff()\
.fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)
df['days_ago_cumsum'] = df.groupby('id')['days_ago'].cumsum()
```

And, this is the function for calculating that flag

```
def get_fixed_day_flag(days_ago_cumsum, within=14):
while True:
    cond = days_ago_cumsum >= within
    days_ago_cumsum_min = days_ago_cumsum.where(cond).min()
    new_days_ago_cumsum = days_ago_cumsum.where(cond) - days_ago_cumsum_min

    cond = new_days_ago_cumsum.notna()
    days_ago_cumsum[cond] = new_days_ago_cumsum[cond].astype(int)

    if days_ago_cumsum.max() < within:
        return days_ago_cumsum == 0
```

And, finished with these 2 lines

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby('id')['days_ago_cumsum'].transform(get_fixed_day_flag)
df['flag'] = df['flag'] & ~df.duplicated(subset=['date','id'])
```

Comment: Thank you this also works! The different approaches are interesting

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is complicated as the flagging depends on the last one which can be any number of rows before. I think you need to create your own function to get the `True` per group of id, but first ensure that the date column is datetime. Then you can do:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

def create_flag(x, nb_days = 14):
    # calculate the delta in days with the first value
    arr = (x - x.min()).dt.days.values
    # create an array to get the flags
    flag = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=bool)
    # change the first value
    flag[0] = True
    # iterate over the all data
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        # once over xx days
        if arr[i] >= nb_days:
            #remove this value to the rest of the arr to restart the count from this flag
            arr[i:] -= arr[i]
            # add the flag to true 
            flag[i] = True
    return pd.DataFrame( {'flag':flag, 'last_flag': x[flag]}, # mask x with flag to get the date of flagging
                         index=x.index).ffill()  # ffill for the date
df[['flag','last_flag']] = df.groupby('id').date.apply(create_flag)
print (df)
        date  id   flag  last_flag
0 2019-01-01  38   True 2019-01-01
1 2019-01-05  16   True 2019-01-05
2 2019-01-10  38  False 2019-01-01
3 2019-01-15  38   True 2019-01-15
4 2019-01-21  38  False 2019-01-15
5 2019-01-30  16   True 2019-01-30
6 2019-02-02  38   True 2019-02-02
7 2019-02-02  38  False 2019-02-02
8 2019-02-03  38  False 2019-02-02
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I like the for loop within a defined variable